# Eclipse doesn't rebuild project on file save

Tags: android, eclipse

Recently my Eclipse started to ignore java files changes and doesn't rebuild project automatically.

I change file, save it, then trying to launch it on device and see in logs that "application is already installed. This is means that apps on device and on desktop are identical.

If I uninstall app from the device and install again I see old applicaton, with old code. Debugging it is not possible since code is not synced.

Project will rebuild ok after cleanup or after resources changes but it's real pain to rebuild whole project after every code change.

It is just last few days. Why is it? Bad recent Eclipse autoupdate? How to fix it?

My Eclipse seems to be latest version available, IDE 4.3.2, no updates available, latest ADT.

Here is my build settings

[image]

Comment: It is set (----------)

Comment: It seems like a last update, IDE 4.3.2, no updates available, latest ADT

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Build

Then look to see if 'Skip packaging and dexing until export or launch' is checked. If so then uncheck it.

Comment: Unchecked. Not helped.

Comment: @nickes : Sorry, not sure I can offer any further advice. Other than Project -> 'Build Automatically` I can't think of any other settings. The screenshot you show is for the workspace but things can be overriden at different level.